# Why is my stack trace being truncated?

Tags: c#, wpf, stack-trace, code-access-security

I have a partial-trust AppDomain within which I run a full-trust debugging window. Using `PermissionSetAttribute` to get permissions I can create the window and do plenty of things with it, but sometimes a SecurityException will be thrown during data binding.

One easily reproducible case throws this: `Property accessor 'Namespace' on object 'System.RuntimeType' threw the following exception:'Request failed.'`. Digging into the exception I can see that it was thrown when full trust was demanded.

No problem, the debug window assembly has full trust and I simply need to assert it. But when I look at the stack trace of the inner `SecurityException` I see this:

```
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(PermissionSet permSet, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Security.PermissionSet.Demand()
   at System.SecurityUtils.DemandGrantSet(Assembly assembly)
   at System.SecurityUtils.DemandReflectionAccess(Type type)
   at System.SecurityUtils.MethodInfoInvoke(MethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] args)
   at System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue(Object component)
```

It ends right there, at `ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue`.

In Visual Studio's Call Stack window I can see `ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue` at the very tip of the stack. *That* stack goes all the way back to the creation of the debug window and the security assert I performed there, which is exactly what I want.

Why has the stack been split in two like this? How can I stop it from happening?

I'm using .Net 4.0 security (i.e. Level 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't that odd. Visual studio's call stack is showing you the method which you were at when the **current** exception was thrown . The `InnerException` shows the callstack of where the **inner exception** exception occurred. After the inner exception was thrown, it propagated up the callstack thus unwinding it until it got to `ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue`. At that point, it was caught in a catch block and set as the inner exception of a new exception which then thrown and bubbled all the way up. So the call stack for the second exception begins at the point it was thrown (i.e. `ReflectPropertyDescriptor.GetValue`)

Here's a simple example which reproduces this.

```
namespace Exceptions
{
    class ExceptionTester
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            ThrowSecondException();
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {
            DoMore();
        }

        public void DoMore()
        {
            ThrowFirstException();
        }

        public void ThrowFirstException()
        {
            throw new FooException();
        }

        public void ThrowSecondException()
        {
            try
            {
                DoSomething();
            }
            catch (FooException e)
            {
                throw new BarException("derp", e);
            }
        }
    }

    class FooException : Exception
    {

    }
    class BarException : Exception
    {
        public BarException(string msg, Exception inner) : base(msg, inner)
        {
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tester = new ExceptionTester();
            tester.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

When the second exception of type `BarException` is thrown, you'll notice that visual studio has `ThrowSecondException` at the top of the call stack because that is where `BarException` was thrown. However, when you dig into `BarException's` `InnerException` and look at `FooException's` call stack, it'll show you where `FooException` was thrown (`ThrowFirstException()`).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I've been able to hack your example around a bit to prove that the CAS stack walk isn't affected by the split, so it seems that I've been looking in the wrong area.